# Is it expensive converting points between coordinate systems?

Tags: coordinate-system

I'm storing lots of points in PostGIS that I use on a webmap. My understanding is that anything webmap related (maplibre/arcgis-js/openlayers/leaflet) etc needs to render in `3857`. But because it's easier to read points in `4326` that is how I am storing them.

I am rendering these points as a vector layer served via `maplibre-gl`, which I guess is transforming the points from `4326` to `3857` on the fly. This seems to work fine, but I'm wondering if there would be noticeable performance improvements if I stored the points directly in `3857`.

Are transformations between different projections expensive such as serving coordinates stored in `4326` as `3857` vector tiles?

Comment: `My understanding is that anything webmap related (maplibre/arcgis-js/openlayers/leaflet) etc needs to render in 3857`  ~ this is a false understanding

Comment: @nmtoken - thanks. actually I know that openlayers allows for different data in different projections. but on the drawing side of things, is it not still 3857? (assuming that openlayers doesn't allow for actually rendering anything other than 3857)

Comment: `is it not still 3857?` No

Comment: Reading the data from disc and sending them over the network will take more time than the reprojection.

Comment: @nmtoken can you elaborate?

Comment: It's perfectly possible to have a web GIS, such as one built with OpenLayers where all the data, layers, backdrop etc is in say EPSG:3413 (or any other CRS of your choosing).  The data doesn't get translated through EPSG:3857 or rendered as EPSG:3857.   Having EPSG:3857 as the CRS in your web GIS is just an implementation decision.  If you want to use existing open services that provide global backdrops, you may find yourself limited to commonly used CRS, such CRS:84, EPSG:3857, but it doesn't have to be so.

Answer (score 2):

If you are always going to use the points in EPSG 3857, do the reprojection in the database and update the data, and in case of need to export, perform the reverse conversion. It will certainly be faster as it eliminates the need for on-the-fly reprojection